# Google Font with Styled Components and Expo

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo, styled-components

I'm working on a managed workflow Expo React Native app and am using Google Fonts (Nunito Sans specifically). I imported the font from `@expo-google-fonts/nunito-sans` and am loading it using the `useFonts` hook.

When using the font in styled components like `font-family: "Nunito Sans"`, I get the error that:

```
fontFamily "Nunito Sans" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

- If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.
```

Is there any way I can still load Nunito Sans using useFonts?